# Version mismatch when installing vue-apollo in Vue 3.0 application

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo, vuejs3

I set up a new Vue 3.0 application using

```
vue create
```

Then I add apollo to my application using

```
vue add apollo
```

Then when I run `npm run build` I get the following error

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                    

Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):


Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@3.0.0 (C:\workspace\StatusTool\dummy-project\node_modules\vue\index.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.12 (C:\workspace\StatusTool\dummy-project\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.


Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseComponent' of undefined
    at parse (C:\workspace\StatusTool\dummy-project\node_modules\@vue\component-compiler-utils\dist\parse.js:15:23)
    at Object.module.exports (C:\workspace\StatusTool\dummy-project\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js:67:22)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Version Information:

- @vue/cli: 4.5.6
- vue-cli-plugin-apollo: "0.22.2"
- apollo: 2.31.0

Seems like package vue-apollo is not installed

Comment: what's the vue-apollo version?

Comment: Added version information to question. Can't find vue-apollo in the list of installed packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `vue/cli: 4.5.6`  instead you need to use [Manual install](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/installation.html#manual-installation)

`vue add apollo` is only for [vue-cli 3](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-cli-plugin-apollo) projects.

It is simple to install.

```
npm install --save vue-apollo graphql apollo-boost
```

or

```
yarn add vue-apollo graphql apollo-boost
```

You still will be able to use [apollo-boost](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/installation.html#apollo-boost)

Comment: Where would I find information about all the other pitfalls I'm going to encounter when using Vue 3.0?

Comment: vue-cli 3 is different project then vue.js version 3. There will be no problem when using vuejs version 3 when it will be released. But current version of vuejs is v2.6.11